# No bluetooth adapters avaliable | Arco Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux, macbook, plasma-tv

I'm using an a1369 macbook air, running kde plasma. Bluedevil outputs No bluetooth adapters avaliable, and blueman is also disfunctional.

I saw https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=381073 this post however it is not realistic for me to go down to the 5.4 kernel.

installed:
bluez bluez-utils bluez-utils-compt broadcomm-wl broadcom-wl-dkms broadcom-bt-firmware blueman

tried:

systemctl enable bluetooth
systemctl start bluetooth
systemctl start dbus
sudo modprobe btusb

outputs:

lsmod | grep blue

```
bluetooth            1089536  14 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 40960  9 bluetooth,brcmsmac,cfg80211
crc16                  12288  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00e9]
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13fe:5200 Phison Electronics Corp. DataTraveler R3.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8404 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:850a Apple, Inc. FaceTime Camera
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05ac:024c Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 05ac:821f Apple, Inc. Built-in Bluetooth 2.0+EDR HCI
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 05ac:820b Apple, Inc. Bluetooth HID Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05ac:820a Apple, Inc. Bluetooth HID Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

sudo dmesg | grep Blue

```
[    1.931453] usb 3-1.1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    8.722349] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.722383] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.722389] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.722393] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.722398] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.910087] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.910093] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.910099] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: I found no other relevant solutions in any other distro. I just mentioned it in case it would help others solve my issue, and ended it on that.

I specifically said that is was not realistic, and I was considering nothing.